# React page / layout transitions with useLayoutEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have following structure defined in order to animate transitions between layouts based on pathname.

```
<LayoutTransition pathname={pathname}>
  {pathname.includes('/registration') && <RegistrationLayout />}
  {pathname.includes('/dashboard') && <DashboardLayout />}
</LayoutTransition>
```

`RegistrationLayout` and `DashboardLayout` have similar structure inside, but they display different pages based on pathname as opposed to layouts.

Inside my `LayoutTransition` component I have following logic

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Root paths are "/registration" "/dashboard"

    const rootPathname = pathname.split('/')[1];
    const rootPrevPathname = prevPathname.current.split('/')[1];

    if (rootPathname !== rootPrevPathname) {
      /*
       * Logic that:
       * 1. Animates component to 0 opacity
       * 2. Sets activeChildren to null
       * 3. Animates component to 1 opacity
       */
    }

    return () => {
      // Sets activeChildren to current one
      setActiveChildren(children);
    };
  }, [pathname]);

  /* renders activeChildren || children */
```

In general this concept works i.e I see my "current" children while animating **out** then as `activeChildren` are set to null, I see my "new" children when animating **in**.

Only issue is that it seems as if when I set `setActiveChildren(children);` layout re-renders, I see flicker and page that layout was displaying returns to its initial state.

Is there a way to avoid this and sort of freeze children when we are animating out, so no re-render on them happens?

**EDIT: Full code snippet from react-native project**

Core idea is that we subscribe to router context, when rootPathname changes we animate current layout (children) out and then animate new ones in.

```
import React, { useContext, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';
import RouterCtx from '../context/RouterCtx';
import useAnimated from '../hooks/useAnimated';
import { durationSlow, easeInQuad } from '../services/Animation';

/**
 * Types
 */
interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

/**
 * Component
 */
function AnimRouteLayout({ children }: IProps) {
  const { routerState } = useContext(RouterCtx);
  const { rootPathname } = routerState;
  const [activeChildren, setActiveChildren] = useState<React.ReactNode>(undefined);
  const [pointerEvents, setPointerEvents] = useState(true);
  const prevRootPathname = useRef<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [animatedValue, startAnimation] = useAnimated(1, {
    duration: durationSlow,
    easing: easeInQuad,
    useNativeDriver: true
  });

  function animationLogic(finished: boolean, value: number) {
    setPointerEvents(false);
    if (finished) {
      if (value === 0) {
        setActiveChildren(undefined);
        startAnimation(1, animationLogic, { delay: 150 });
      }
      setPointerEvents(true);
    }
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (prevRootPathname.current) {
      if (rootPathname !== prevRootPathname.current) {
        startAnimation(0, animationLogic);
      }
    }

    return () => {
      prevRootPathname.current = rootPathname;
      setActiveChildren(children);
    };
  }, [rootPathname]);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      pointerEvents={pointerEvents ? 'auto' : 'none'}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        opacity: animatedValue.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [0, 1] }),
        transform: [
          {
            scale: animatedValue.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [1.1, 1] })
          }
        ]
      }}
    >
      {activeChildren || children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

export default AnimRouteLayout;
```

Comment: Is there another place where `setActiveChildren` is called? It would help to see the `useState` call (I'm assuming `setActiveChildren` is a setter from `useState`) and the exact code for any lines that deal with that state. Something is causing the children to re-mount, but it is difficult to be certain of why without seeing more of the details.

Comment: @RyanCogswellI was trying to keep my question simple, as it is based on react-native component. Same logic applies though. I added full code snipper to the question with some explanation. Right now I need to figure out a way how to make `activeChildren` a sort of frozen snapshot of children that doesn't change based on router context changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll describe what I believe is happening with your current code by laying out the steps that would occur when a user starts at "/registration" and then switches to "/dashboard":

- Initial render of `AnimRouteLayout` with `rootPathname='/registration'`

  - initial layout effect is queued
  - `activeChildren` is undefined, so `children` is returned to be rendered
  - `<RegistrationLayout />` is rendered
  - the queued layout effect executes

    - `prevRootPathname.current` is undefined, so no animation
    - layout effect cleanup is registered with React
- User switches to "/dashboard" triggering render of `AnimRouteLayout` with `rootPathname='/dashboard'`

  - since `rootPathname` is different, a second layout effect is queued
  - `activeChildren` is still undefined, so `children` is returned to be rendered
  - `<RegistrationLayout />` unmounts and `<DashboardLayout />` is rendered
  - the cleanup for the previous layout effect executes

    - `prevRootPathname.current` gets set to '/registration'
    - `activeChildren` gets set to the previous children causing another render to be queued
  - the queued layout effect executes and starts the animation
  - another render of `AnimRouteLayout` begins due to the `activeChildren` state change
  - an additional layout effect is **not** queued because `rootPathname` is not different
  - `activeChildren` is returned to be rendered
  - `<DashboardLayout />` unmounts
  - `<RegistrationLayout />` remounts with fresh state and is rendered
  - animation completes and sets `activeChildren` back to undefined
  - `AnimRouteLayout` renders again and this time `<DashboardLayout />` will be rendered

Though it would be possible to manage `activeChildren` in a manner that prevents the re-mounting, I think there is a cleaner way to approach this problem. Rather than trying to freeze the **children**, I think you would be better off to freeze the **pathname**. I did a fair amount of experimentation with these ideas when writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452549/react-router-transition-in-and-out-events/53907021#53907021). The terminology I came up with to keep this straight is to distinguish between:

- `targetPathname` The path the user has indicated they want to be on
- `renderPathname` The path currently being rendered

Most of the time these paths will be the same. The exception is during the exit transition when `renderPathname` will have the value of the previous `targetPathname`. With this approach you would have something like the following:

```
<AnimRouteLayout targetPathname={pathname}>
  {(renderPathname)=> {
    return <>
      {renderPathname.includes('/registration') && <RegistrationLayout />}
      {renderPathname.includes('/dashboard') && <DashboardLayout />}
    </>;
  }}
</AnimRouteLayout>
```

and then `AnimRouteLayout` just needs to manage `renderPathname` appropriately:

```
function AnimRouteLayout({ children, targetPathname }) {
  const [renderPathname, setRenderPathname] = useState(targetPathname);
  // End of animation would set renderPathname to targetPathname
  return children(renderPathname);
}
```

Since I didn't try to make a working example of this, I make no guarantees that I don't have a syntax accident in the above, but I'm fairly confident the approach is sound.

Comment: Amazing answer, I will try to apply your approach latter today and will comment back here with the result!

Comment: I must say, this is such a simple and elegant solution Ryan. I have it working now :)